# How is componentDidMount used even after state is changed?

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and came across this code:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The question is how is componentDidMount called even after state gets changed, that is,

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(
          () => this.tick(),
          1000
        );
      }
```

in right above code setInterval is called which in turn calls tick function that changes state. But after  the state changes and after the component is re-rendered, is componentDidMount called again?

Comment: componentDidMount will only be called on the first time Clock component got rendered

Answer (score 1):

> is componentDidMount called again?

No, it won't be called again. In a component render `componentDidMount` gets called once ***on the first render only***. If you need to get the previous value again there is another lifecycle method for this [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). Something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    console.log(prevState);
}
```

Comment: but how is it possible that tick is called every second which changes state every second since componentDidMount is called only once?

Comment: That is what `setInterval` does. componentDidMount just initializes the code written in the block. In your case it is `this.tick()` each second.

Answer (score 1):

No you're mistaken, the `componentDidMount` is called only once after render, it's the `tick` function which is called again and again after every second. Let me elaborate:

After render ->

1. `componentDidMount` is called. Inside it the `setInterval` get called.
2. `setInterval` gets queued in the event queue, returns an id (a number) to `this.timerID` and `componentDidMount` exits.
3. The `tick` function is pushed to the stack and executed after one second duration.
4. Since it's a `setInterval`, it's there in the queue and again gets executed after one second.
5. Pattern is followed...

I understand that you're confused as to how the `tick` is called again and again and not the `componentDidMount`. See the following:

```
fuction parentFunction() {
  setInterval(() => {
    childFunction();
  }, 1000);
}

parentFunction();
```

In ths scenario, the `childFunction` is inside the `setInterval` (the `parentFunction` is not) and hence only `childFunction` is called again and again, and not the `parentFunction`.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

A component will mount when it's rendered for the first time or after an unmount or when you change the key prop.

So if you have a component named `WillSometimesRender` it will unmount when it was rendered before but is not rendered now.

And if you have a component named `KeyChange` it will unmount when rendered with a different key and then remount (see code below)

```js
class KeyChange extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('key change got mounted');
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('key change got unmounted');
  }
  render() {
    return <div>key change</div>;
  }
}
class WillSometimesRender extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('will sometimes render got mounted');
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('will sometimes render got unmounted');
  }
  render() {
    return <div>will sometimes render</div>;
  }
}
const App = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = React.useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setKey(key => key + 1)}>
        Change key
      </button>
      <KeyChange key={key} />
      {key % 2 && <WillSometimesRender />}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```